# Simulate HttpRequestException for unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, httpclient

I have an application that downloads massive amounts of pdfs from the web. From time to time, I get a HttpRequestException, contaning the message: Error while copying content to a stream.

So, I am trying to unit test my code to handle this situation. My current code for downloading is:

```
var request = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

// This is where the exception would be thrown
await request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
```

Now I am trying to simulate a HttpRequestException, so that I can unit test the code above, but I dont know how to do it. Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Abstract the httpClient call behind an interface you control so that you can mock it during unit test to raise/simulate the exception you want. also from a naming perspective, the result of `GetAsync` would be the `response` not `request`. ie `var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);`

Comment: I hadn't considered this use case. I'll look at adding a new API to mockhttp to make it easier in the future.

Comment: Thanks. Please, update when possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is creating an `HttpContent` that throws an exception:

```
public class ExceptionThrowingContent : HttpContent
{
    private readonly Exception exception;
    public ExceptionThrowingContent(Exception exception)
    {
        this.exception = exception;
    }

    protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromException(exception);
    }

    protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
    {
        length = 0L;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Once you have that, you can use something like my own [mockhttp](https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp) to mock the request:

```
var handler = new MockHttpMessageHandler();
handler.When("http://tempuri.org/url")
    .Respond(new ExceptionThrowingContent(ex));

var mockClient = new HttpClient(handler);

// pass mockHandler to your component
```

Now, if your component passes in `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` when it makes the request, the exception will be thrown at `await Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()`. If not, HttpClient will attempt to buffer the response so the exception will be thrown at `await HttpClient.GetAsync()`.

If the response *is* being buffered, it's realistically "impossible" for an exception to be thrown at `ReadAsByteArrayAsync` so there's no point in attempting to simulate it. ("impossible" outside an `OutOfMemoryException`)

Comment: Looks really great!!! Do you think it is possible to have the exception thrown at await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(); ? I was not clear enough :( Sorry. As of now, the exception is being thrown at await await mockClient.GetAsync("http://tempuri.org/url")

Comment: Updated to return an exception-throwing Task instead. Give that a go.

Comment: Did not work :(. If you could spare some time to check this out, I would really appreciate it

Comment: @FernandoSilva Updated

Comment: Still giving me the exception on GetAsync :(

Comment: What does your call to `GetAsync` look like? What `HttpCompletionOption` value is it passing in?

Answer (score 1):

With [MockHttp](https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp) it is easy setup `HttpClient` tests in a fluent manner you can return a customized `HttpContent` that throws a `HttpRequestException` like in this example.

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(HttpRequestException))]
public async Task Test()
{
    var content = new ContentWithException();
    var mockHttp = new MockHttpMessageHandler();
    mockHttp.Expect("http://localhost/mypdfDownload").Respond(content);

    var client = new HttpClient(mockHttp);
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost/mypdfDownload");

    await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
}

private class ContentWithException : HttpContent
{
    protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
    {
        throw new HttpRequestException();
    }

    protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
    {
        length = 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks really great!!! Do you think it is possible to have the exception thrown at await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(); ? I was not clear enough :( Sorry.

As of now, the exception is being thrown at await client.GetAsync("http://localhost/mypdfDownload")

Comment: @FernandoSilva: I looked into it and I have not come up with a solution yet. In both cases (like in the answer from @Richard Szalay) the HttpClient begins in `GetAsync` to access the content (async buffering). So the exception is thrown there and not later on in `ReadAsByteArrayAsync()`. I'll give it a thought on another solution.